# Getting home directory?

Tags: macos, powershell, powershell-core

I'm trying to get a directory off of the user's home directory in a script.  This is what I'm trying, but the `~` is interperated as a literal instead of expanding to the home directory.  Is there anyway to get it to expand?  If not, can I get the home directory another way?

```
$mySourceDir = "~/Projects/svn/myProject/trunk" # Single quote also does not expand
cd $mySourceDir
```

This is using the PS 6 beta on OSX.

Comment: `$x = "~/test/"` then `cd $x` works for me on PS 6 on Linux with the variable quoted

Comment: What's this have to do with `OS X`?

Comment: @l'L'l PowerShell is now also available on several Unix platforms, including macOS (OS X) (in beta, as of this writing) - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell. That said, the problem at hand can be solved in a platform-agnostic manner.

Comment: @l'L'l What mllement0 said, and I am actually specifically trying this on OSX.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying; I wasn't aware of the OS X version, but now I am!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In PowerShell, the most robust way to refer to the current user's home directory is to **use automatic variable `$HOME`, inside `"..."` if it is part of a larger path**:

- `$mySourceDir = "$HOME/Projects/svn/myProject/trunk"; Set-Location $mySourceDir`
  (`Set-Location` is PowerShell's `cd` equivalent; thanks to a built-in alias definition, you can use `cd` too, however.)
- If you're passing a path as an *argument* to a *command*, you may be able to get away without the enclosing `"..."`, depending on what characters the path contains; e.g.,
  `Set-Location $HOME/Desktop`
- **Works on both Windows and Unix platforms**, whereas if you tried to use *environment* variables such as `$env:HOME`, platform differences would surface.
- To learn about all automatic variables (built-in variables) that PowerShell defines, see the conceptual [`about_Automatic_Variables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables) help topic (as of this writing, the description of `$HOME` reflects just the *Windows* perspective, but `$HOME` does work analogously on Unix platforms).

---

**Use `~` only if you're certain that the current location is a *filesystem* location:**

- The current *location* is PowerShell's generalized concept of the current *directory*: PowerShell generalizes the concept of a *drive* to include other (typically) hierarchical data stores, such as the Windows registry, a directory of all defined functions (drive `Function:`), variables (`Variable`), or environment variables (`Env:`).
- Each such drive is provided by a *drive provider*, of which the *filesystem* [drive provider] is just *one* instance.
- **`~`** is a *drive-provider-specific* concept, so using just `~`, without an explicit reference to a drive provider, **refers to the home location *as defined by the provider underlying the current location***.

  - Some providers provide *no default* for what `~` represents, causing attempts to use it to fail; for instance, that is the case for the `Environment` drive provider and its `Env:` drive:
    `Set-Location Env:; Set-Location ~` results in error
    `Home location for this provider is not set. To set the home location, call "(get-psprovider 'Environment').Home = 'path'`
- It is the *drive provider* that interprets `~`, so **`~` also works inside `'...'` and `"..."`**

  - From a filesystem location, the following commands all work the same:

    - `Set-Location ~/Desktop`
    - `Set-Location "~/Desktop"`
    - `Set-Location '~/Desktop'`
  - Contrast this with POSIX-like shells such as `bash`, where it is the *shell* that expands `~`, up front, before the target command sees it, but only if it is *unquoted*.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$mySourceDir = "$env:HOME/Projects/svn/myProject/trunk"
```

Comment: Wouldn't just `$HOME/...` work? and you've got two double-quotes at the end of the command...

Comment: I don't have $env:home. Just HOMEPATH and HOMEDRIVE.

Comment: @Matt, that's true on _Windows_, but `HOME` _is_ an environment variable on Unix-like platforms (macOS and Linux), and the question mentions macOS (OSX). That said, using PowerShell's automatic `$HOME` variable instead makes for a platform-agnostic solution.